# JGit: Find all commit logs with pattern/substring in commit message

Tags: java, jgit

I want to find all commit logs having "type: MY_TYPE" in the commit message. 
I can do this by git command `git log --grep=<pattern>`

How to do this with Jgit. I am not able to find any example for the same

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572483/how-to-do-git-grep-e-pattern-with-jgit

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572483/how-to-do-git-grep-e-pattern-with-jgit gives solution for finding a pattern in the source (git grep). I want to match pattern in commit messages (git log --grep). As mentioned in that thread, PatternMatchRevFilter may help, but I am not finding any example on how to use it for my purpose